# Reply to an email with "First Name Last Name", not with "Last Name, First Name", with a particular font

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to reply to an email in an organisation, using my own font and color with some minor changes to the codes available on https://www.extendoffice.com/fi/documents/outlook/5417-outlook-dear-first-name.html

```vb
Public WithEvents GExplorer As Outlook.Explorer
Public WithEvents GMailItem As Outlook.MailItem

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set GExplorer = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer
End Sub

Private Sub GExplorer_SelectionChange()
    Dim xItem As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xItem = GExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
    If xItem.Class <> olMail Then Exit Sub
    Set GMailItem = xItem
End Sub

Private Sub GMailItem_Reply(ByVal Response As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    AutoAddGreetingToReply Response
End Sub

Private Sub GMailItem_ReplyAll(ByVal Response As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    AutoAddGreetingToReply Response
End Sub

Sub AutoAddGreetingToReply(Item As Object)
    Dim xGreetStr As String
    Dim xReplyMail As MailItem
    Dim xSenderName As String
    Dim xRecipient As Recipient
    On Error Resume Next
    If Item.Class <> olMail Then Exit Sub
    Set xReplyMail = Item
    For Each xRecipient In xReplyMail.Recipients
        If xSenderName = "" Then
            xSenderName = xRecipient.Name
        Else
            xSenderName = xSenderName & "," & xRecipient.Name
        End If
    Next xRecipient
    Select Case Time
           Case 0.3 To 0.5
                xGreetStr = " Good morning, thank you for your email."
           Case 0.5 To 0.75
                xGreetStr = " Good afternoon, thank you for your email."
           Case Else
                xGreetStr = " Good evening, thank you for your email."
    End Select
    With xReplyMail
        .Display
        .HTMLBody = "<HTML><Body>Dear " & xSenderName & ",</HTML></Body>" & xGreetStr & .HTMLBody
    End With
End Sub
```

I receive the following. The code is copying the exact layout of the person who emailed me.

[image]

I want to amend this code to have something like

[image]

Furthermore, when I run this code I can not use ctrl-z to undo.

Comment: In general, "undo" will not work on an action that is carried out with VBA. This is seen across the office-package, where in all cases the running of a macro/VBA-code will clear the undo stack

Comment: @Prebsus Thank you for this information, I did not know this so to make it work again, I can simply close VBA? Or will it keep running in the background and I can not do anything about it?

Comment: not sure if I fully understand, but in the undo-stack will keep building (storing your old actions) as normal when you're not running any VBA-code. However, as soon as you run a line of VBA-code, the undo-stack will clear. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You must get a well-formed HTML markup to get it working as required, but now you are trying to append a document with an existing markup, here is your current code:

```
.HTMLBody = "<HTML><Body>Dear " & xSenderName & ",</HTML></Body>" & xGreetStr & .HTMLBody
```

Instead, you must find an opening `<body>` tag and insert your own text right after the tag.

```
.HTMLBody = .HTMLBody.FindTheBodyElement().PasteYourStuff()
```

So, you will get a well-formed HTML markup with opening and closing `<body>` tags.

Comment: Hello @Eugene, I do not see any differences between what you proposed and my question, would you mind giving detail information about what you mean? At least like a good example where you change minor things in the original code to give me an idea? Thank you so much

Comment: It is your code shown as an example. Anyway, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you for this but, I am new to VBA what do you mean by PasteYourStuff()? Like do you mean in reference to my provided example?

Comment: This a raw sketch showing you an approach. You can use [string functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/functions/string-functions) available in VBA.